# React Material-Ui(0.20.0) dialog not show expected results?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-modal

React Material-Ui has the `Dialog` component which has the property `modal`, when i change it to `true` or `false` it show me the same result what does this property means?

it is really confusing me kindly help me?

Material Ui version:0.20.0

**Code**

```
 <Dialog
        modal={true}
        open={props.openClose}
        autoScrollBodyContent={true}>

             {props.children}
 </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Modal dialog` is apparently similar to the other dialogs but `Modal dialog` can only be closed by selecting one of the actions.

Comment: what is the difference in between the modal=true and modal=false?

Comment: when you pas `modal={true}` to `Modal` component the `Modal` will be `Modal dialog` and you can know the difference in my answer.

Comment: @Sunny this answer was helpful?

Comment: No my question was little bit different

Answer (score 0):

According to the Material UI documentation, the property which handles the visibility of Dialog is `open`.

In your example, you have given as `open={props.openClose}`. Please update the same with `true` or `false` and check the result.

Check the [example](https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/)

Also, please find the API documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/)